# Flux - Cancelled and Terminated not mutually exclusive?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am trying to wrap a tracing span around a Flux execution and want to treat the "cancelled"-signal specially by adding a tag using doOnCancel while I use doOnTerminate for regular termination of the Flux.

That is when I noticed that there are cases where the Flux is treated as cancelled even though it also terminated. Is that by design? My understanding was that those states would be mutually exclusive.

```
Flux.just("a")
            .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("cancelled"))
            .doOnTerminate(() -> System.out.println("terminated"))
            .blockFirst();
```

This prints:
cancelled
terminated

Is there a way to find out if the Flux was cancelled but did not terminate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two signals are indeed not mutually exclusive in the Reactive Streams specification: a cancellation is async and can be done while the `Publisher` is calling the cancelling `Subscriber`'s `onComplete` or `onError` method, hence the possibility that these two side effects are both called.

A cancelled `Subscription` MAY even push a few `onNext` events (conceptually, such `onNext` would be "in-flight" at the instant the subscription is cancelled).